# error: prototype does not match any in class

Tags: c++, class, templates, prototype

I'm getting this error when I try to compile my code:

```
Priority_queue.h:63:6: error: prototype for ‘void Priority_queue<T>::push_heap(Iterator, Iterator)’ does not match any in class ‘Priority_queue<T>’
 void Priority_queue<T>::push_heap(Iterator start, Iterator stop) {
      ^
Priority_queue.h:31:10: error: candidate is: void Priority_queue<T>::push_heap(typename std::vector<T>::iterator, typename std::vector<T>::iterator)
     void push_heap(typename vector<T>::iterator start, typename vector<T>::iterator stop);
          ^
```

**Priority_queue.h**

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Priority_queue {
public:
    ...

    void push_heap(typename vector<T>::iterator start, typename vector<T>::iterator stop);
    void pop_heap(typename vector<T>::iterator start, typename vector<T>::iterator stop);
    void adjust_heap(typename vector<T>::iterator start, unsigned int heapSize, unsigned int position);
    void make_heap(typename vector<T>::iterator start, typename vector<T>::iterator stop);
    void sort_heap(typename vector<T>::iterator start, typename vector<T>::iterator stop);
    void heap_sort(typename vector<T>::iterator start, typename vector<T>::iterator stop);
private:
    vector<T> c;
};

template <class T>
template <class Iterator>
void Priority_queue<T>::push_heap(Iterator start, Iterator stop) {
...
}
```

Why does this not work? I get the same type of error for the rest of the functions as well.

Comment: The error message is clear; the decalration and definition don't match.

Comment: I understand what the error is saying, but why do they not match?  Is the template "Iterator" causing problems?  I tried replacing "Iterator" in the defintion parameters with "vector<T>::iterator" like in the declaration, and got an error saying "variable or field ‘push_heap’ declared void"

Comment: Yes, I tried that too but I get the same "prototype does not match" error.

Comment: Please show the code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear; the decalration and definition don't match. `push_heap` is declared as a member function of class template `Priority_queue`, but defined as a member function *template* of class template `Priority_queue`.

How to fix it depends on your original intent; you could change the declaration to

```
template <class T>
class Priority_queue {
public:
    ...
    template <class Iterator>
    void push_heap(Iterator start, Iterator stop);
    ...
};
```

[LIVE1](http://rextester.com/LQYO23549)

or change the definition to

```
template <class T>
void Priority_queue<T>::push_heap(typename vector<T>::iterator start, typename vector<T>::iterator stop) {
...
}
```

[LIVE2](http://rextester.com/TLZVE57742)

Comment: Thank you, the first solution is what I intended.  I was declaring "template <class Iterator>" outside the class, so I'm guessing that was the issue.

Comment: @user2628156 Yes, if you want it to be a member function template, then you need to specify this at the declaration too; i.e. write the `template <class Iterator>` part.